# How to display fields at the beginning of PyCharm code completion?

Tags: pycharm, code-completion

I would like PyCharm to show firstly fields, and then methods; i.e. firstly members marked with the 'f' icon, and then with the 'm' icon.

Is it possible? There is no such option in *Settings > Editor > General > Code Completion*.

[image: PyCharm code completion]